# GUI support will not compile in latest from github

Tags: gvim, linux, compile-vim

I'm using CentOS 7.5.  I just did a `git pull` in my clone of the vim repo to the latest: last tag `v8.2.2340`.  I'm trying to compile.  No matter what I do, it will not compile for the GUI (which it's always done before).  Usually, I do nothing more than `./configure && make && sudo make install` and all works.

After fiddling with the options to `configure` I still cannot get it to compile a GUI.  I found this in the git log

```
commit 67876de7bbc4254268d8180d68203b965e25ed95 (tag: v8.2.2337)
Author: Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
Date:   Tue Jan 12 20:51:24 2021 +0100

    patch 8.2.2337: configure test for GTK only says "no"
    
    Problem:    Configure test for GTK only says "no". (Harm te Hennepe)
    Solution:   Hint that a -def package is needed. (closes #5229)
```

Apparently, someone else noted similar issues and the fix was to "hint" that `-devel` packages are needed.  At least, I think they're talking about `devel` packages.  The commit/tag comment says "-def" package.  The problem, I have them.

```
$ rpm -qa gtk\*-deve\*
gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
gtk+-devel-1.2.10-77.el7.x86_64
gtk3-devel-3.22.30-3.el7.x86_64
```

I want it to check for gtk2.  The configure script is looking for gtk2 >= 2.2.0 but it always says "no," but yet version **2.24.31** is installed.  What must I do to get the latest vim to compile for the GUI support *that is installed* on my system?

---

**EDIT** It would seem that the problem is due to the order of libraries for linking.  I've been doing more digging and the config.log file shows several lines like this one when running the test for gtk2

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libpango-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_object_replace_qdata'
```

This symbol is in the library `libgobject.so` which is installed on this system.  Indeed, it's even used in the build line when linking.  However, it cannot find these symbols.  If I disable the GTK check, the `configure` script *does find* the GTK2 development libraries installed.

I think this all comes down to ld's irksome "order dependent on the command line" of libraries.

Comment: Yeah, the `-dev` suffix is what such packages are called in Debian/Ubuntu, that corresponds to the CentOS/RHEL/Fedora `-devel` suffix. That specific commit in 8.2.2337 is only printing additional messages and isn't changing the build behavior, so I somewhat doubt it that it's what is breaking your build... I do have a CentOS 7 build of Vim 8.2.1719 but it's using `gtk3-devel` and I'm passing `--enable-gui=gtk3` to `./configure`. Why do you want GTK2 instead of GTK3?

Comment: @filbranden I am using Mate Desktop.  Since it's a fork of gnome2 I thought GTK 2 is what I should use.  However, I'm likely admitting to my ignorance on GUIs.  Are Gnome 2 and GTK2 the same?

Comment: @filbranden well, I just tried with GTK3 and have the same unresolved symbols.  Very strange.

Comment: From my reading of the configure snippet, Vim should use the libraries listed in the output of `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` for linking. On my CentOS system, that's `-lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0`. The `g_object_replace_qdata` symbol comes from `-lgobject-2.0` (`/usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so`) which is included in package `glib2-devel`. Do you have all those packages installed?

Comment: You can also try to run `rpm -V` on a package to see if any of its files are modified, for example `rpm -V glib2-devel` or `rpm -V gtk3-devel`. You can use `rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so` to find the name of the RPM package that ships a specific file too. Finally, take a look at `src/auto/config.log` to see where `./configure` might have broken. Can you find the whole link command-line used that produced that error? Or maybe upload your config.log to a Gist or paste bin?

Comment: @filbranden I finally found the answer.  The problem came down to a local install of an older version of glib.  It took some digging but I found a library reference for glib and one of the functions which I needed `g_task_set_return_on_cancel`.  This function is from 2.36 onward.  For reasons which I no longer recall, I'd installed 2.32, which went to `/usr/local/lib` which superseded the system library of 2.56.  I'm rock'n the latest vim now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer came down to a local install of `glib-2` which, because it was installed to `/usr/local/lib` was superseding the glib-2 installed in `/lib64`.  As an example, a function named `g_task_set_return_on_cancel` which is part of glib v2.36 and later, was not found.  I'd installed 2.32 (for reasons which I have presently forgotten) and it was superseding the system install of 2.58 in `/lib64`.

It could potentially have been solved in a variety of ways.  Since I didn't recall why I installed 2.32 I simply removed it, reran `configure` for vim and rebuilt.  An alternative method would have been to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the duration of the configure and build.  Potentially, some variation of the magic arguments supported by `configure` may also be been used along with other env variables such as `LDFLAGS` or so forth.

Whatever potential solution you should find, if you find something like this, check for "local" installs which may be overshadowing the system install.